# NHibernate 3 - TransactionScope vs. NHibernate transactions

Tags: nhibernate

I need to choose between TransactionScope or NHibernate transactions for my new project.
What is better? When should use TransactionScope? NHibernate transactions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different things.

You should always do your work inside a NHibernate transaction.

You can use TransactionScope as needed, for example. to use distributed transactions when there's more than one session involved.

NHibernate transactions will automatically enlist in distributed transactions, but they won't be created automatically, so the recommended pattern is: if you have a TransactionScope, open the NH transaction inside it.

Comment: Yes, but why do I need to open NHibernate transaction? TransactionScope open a database transaction like NHibernate transaction or not?

Comment: @Andy: because using explicit transactions is always recommended for NHibernate (not doing so breaks caching, among other things), and not having a NH transaction when you have a TransactionScope can result in hard-to-debug bugs. It could be better, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction management is exposed to the application developer via the NHibernate
ITransaction interface. You aren’t forced to use this API—NHibernate lets you
control ADO.NET transactions directly.