# How can I use TransactionScope with SQL Compact 4.0 and NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, sql-server-ce, transactionscope

I am trying to use NHibernate in combination with .NET's TransactionScope object.  So far I have successfully used Oracle 11g and SQL Server 2008R2 with no issues.  However, SQL Compact seems to fall on its face.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TranactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        // The line below throws.  I also tried passing in System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted to no avail
        using (var txn = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            // Perform insert
            txn.Commit();
        }
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

This results in the following exception.  I understand what this means, but I don't understand *why* it is attempting to create a nested transaction.

```
NHibernate.TransactionException: Begin failed with SQL exception ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SqlCeConnection does not support nested transactions.
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
       at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code potentially produces 2 transactions:

```
1)new TransactionScope(TranactionScopeOption.Required)
2)session.BeginTransaction()
```

TransactionScope.Required "uses an ambient transaction if one already exists. Otherwise, it creates a new transaction before entering the scope. This is the default value". Your are guaranteed to have an ambient transaction by time `session.BeginTransaction()` gets hit, hence, making it a nested transaction.

If the transaction scope is not completed everything within its scope will be rolled back.

Comment: My (perhaps incorrect) assumption was that session.BeginTransaction() would enlist in the ambient transaction rather than creating a new one.  After all, how can a transaction be created before any connection is even opened.  Searching more, I just found two interesting, and somewhat conflicting answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080253/missing-support-for-ambient-transactions-in-nhibernate - seems to indicate I shouldn't mix the two; and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574735/nhibernate-3-transactionscope-vs-nhibernate-transactions - seems to indicate it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in this question: [The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554314/ef-transitionscope-the-connection-object-can-not-be-enlisted-in-transaction)

"At a guess, TransactionScope needs to escalate to a distributed or nested transaction, neither of which is supported by CE."

Comment: I understand that; it is what is happening.  What I don't understand is _why_ is needs to escalate.  Clearly there is a single connection, and as I said above, both TransactionScope and BeginTransaction should enlist in an ambient transaction (that's how it works with both SQL Server and Oracle).

Comment: When I use OpenSession() inside a running ISession it would seem to me the inner session uses a different connection (tried it with and without TransactionScope). I think DTC is required if there is more than one open connection. Could it be that it works for you in SQS only because you have MS DTC enabled there?

Comment: A `TransactionScope` object does not open a connection; it's basically just a thread local storage flag that indicates a transaction has been requested.  The code above does not use OpenSession within a running ISession.  No DTC is enabled in my testing.